# WSO2 Axis2 JMS Transport cannot set JMS_DESTINATION on Websphere MQ queue

Tags: jms, apache-axis, wso2, ibm-mq, wso2-esb

I have a simple WSO2 ESB Axis2 JMS transport pulling a message from an ActiveMQ queue and pushing it to a Websphere MQ Queue.

When the message is sent I get the following error

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageFormatException: JMSCC0050: The property name 'JMS_DESTINATION' is reserved and cannot be set
```

I'm not setting any properties explicitly but I wonder if this is the way the WSO2 ESB Axis2 JMS transport sends a message to Websphere MQ?

This works fine the other way Websphere MQ to ActiveMQ.

I am using Client Mode on the JNDI Websphere MQ connection factory and connecting to this via an LDAP server also using the default SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN channel.

Could it be a permissions issue in Websphere MQ?

I ran ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED) to rule out any permissions issues (I hoped).

Proxy Service

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ACTIVETOIBM" transports="jms" statistics="enable" trace="enable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" separator=","/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="jms:/cn=QUEUE.OUT?transport.jms.ConnectionFactory=ibmMQQueueConnectionFactory&transport.jms.Destination=cn=QUEUE.OUT">
                  <markForSuspension>
                     <retryDelay>5</retryDelay>
                  </markForSuspension>
               </address>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="full" category="ERROR" separator=","/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">activeMQQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">QUEUE.IN</parameter>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

axis2 jms transportReceiver config

```
    <transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
        <parameter name="activeMQQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
            <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
        </parameter>

        <parameter name="ibmMQQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
            <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">ldap://localhost:7777/dc=example,dc=com</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">cn=ConnectionFactoryLdap</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
        </parameter>
    </transportReceiver>
```

axis2 jms transportSender config

```
 <transportSender name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender">
     <parameter name="activeMQQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    </parameter>

    <parameter name="ibmMQQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">ldap://localhost:7777/dc=example,dc=com</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">cn=ConnectionFactoryLdapCM</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    </parameter>        
 </transportSender>
```

Full Stack Trace

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageFormatException: JMSCC0050: The property name 'JMS_DESTINATION' is reserved and cannot be set.
The supplied property name begins with the JMS prefix, but is not one of the supported, settable properties.
Check the property name and correct errors.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:233)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:109)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageImpl.checkSettablePropertyName(JmsMessageImpl.java:2125)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageImpl.setStringProperty(JmsMessageImpl.java:1560)
        at com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage.setStringProperty(JMSMessage.java:1496)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.setTransportHeaders(JMSUtils.java:278)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.createJMSMessage(JMSSender.java:441)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendOverJMS(JMSSender.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:154)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[2013-03-15 10:25:35,306] ERROR - AsyncCallback Error creating a JMS message from the message context
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error creating a JMS message from the message context
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.handleException(AbstractTransportSender.java:226)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendOverJMS(JMSSender.java:174)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:154)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageFormatException: JMSCC0050: The property name 'JMS_DESTINATION' is reserved and cannot be set.
The supplied property name begins with the JMS prefix, but is not one of the supported, settable properties.
Check the property name and correct errors.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:233)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:109)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageImpl.checkSettablePropertyName(JmsMessageImpl.java:2125)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageImpl.setStringProperty(JmsMessageImpl.java:1560)
        at com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage.setStringProperty(JMSMessage.java:1496)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.setTransportHeaders(JMSUtils.java:278)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.createJMSMessage(JMSSender.java:441)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendOverJMS(JMSSender.java:172)
        ... 6 more
[2013-03-15 10:25:35,310]  WARN - AsyncCallback Executing fault handler due to exception encountered
[2013-03-15 10:25:35,311]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_CODE : 0
[2013-03-15 10:25:35,311]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_MESSAGE : Error creating a JMS message from the message context
[2013-03-15 10:25:35,311]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_DETAIL : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error creating a JMS message from the message context
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.AsyncCallback.onError(AsyncCallback.java:67)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:643)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error creating a JMS message from the message context
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.handleException(AbstractTransportSender.java:226)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendOverJMS(JMSSender.java:174)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:154)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageFormatException: JMSCC0050: The property name 'JMS_DESTINATION' is reserved and cannot be set.
The supplied property name begins with the JMS prefix, but is not one of the supported, settable properties.
Check the property name and correct errors.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:233)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:109)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageImpl.checkSettablePropertyName(JmsMessageImpl.java:2125)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageImpl.setStringProperty(JmsMessageImpl.java:1560)
        at com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage.setStringProperty(JMSMessage.java:1496)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.setTransportHeaders(JMSUtils.java:278)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.createJMSMessage(JMSSender.java:441)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendOverJMS(JMSSender.java:172)
        ... 6 more

[2013-03-15 10:25:35,313]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_EXCEPTION : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error creating a JMS message from the message context
```

Cheers
Steve

Comment: Ok I found the issue

Looks like Active MQ sets the following headers by default.

    JMS_DESTINATION
    JMS_REDELIVERED
    JMS_TYPE

WebsphereMQ does not allow these to be set by a client.

I removed these headers and now it works.

by adding this in the inSequence             <property name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere MQ JMS library does not allow setting most of transport scope properties.

Therefore you have to remove those before sending to JMS queue.

We need to add following properties before .

```
<property name="JMS_DESTINATION" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
<property name="JMS_REDELIVERED" scope="transport" action="remove" />
<property name="JMS_TYPE" scope="transport" action="remove" /> 
<property name="Accept-Encoding" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
<property name="Content-Length" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
<property name="Content-Type" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
<property name="User-Agent" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
<property name="Transfer-Encoding" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
<property name="X-Forwarded-For" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
<property name="X-Forwarded-Host" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
<property name="X-Forwarded-Server" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
```

But I guess you have already found the solution! :)